# file is encrypted or is not a database, Database not corrupted and password is correct

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

I am facing a strange behavior in my android application. The database is working when I begins the application and the tables are created and information are entered to the database.

But when I sign out from the application and logins again I am getting the error.

```
07-04 02:54:03.427 5171-5877/? E/Database: CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
07-04 02:54:03.427 5171-5877/? E/Database: Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
                                           net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database
                                               at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
                                               at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:2474)
                                               at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabaseInternal(SQLiteDatabase.java:2338)
                                               at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1087)
                                               at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1150)
                                               at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:162)
                                               at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:129)
                                               at com.package.helper.MyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(MyOpenHelper.java:58)
                                               at com.package.provider.MyContentProvider.query(MyContentProvider.java:31)
                                               at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:857)
                                               at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:200)
                                               at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:461)
                                               at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompatJellybean.query(ContentResolverCompatJellybean.java:29)
                                               at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat$ContentResolverCompatImplJB.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:57)
                                               at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:125)
                                               at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:59)
                                               at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:37)
                                               at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:296)
                                               at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:54)
                                               at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:42)
                                               at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:128)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

MyOpenHelper.java

```
@ContextSingleton
public class MyOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    Context context;
    private static final String PWD = "databse password";

    @Inject
    public MyOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Constants.DB_NAME, null, 25);
        this.context = context;
        SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
        return getWritableDatabase(PWD);
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
        return getReadableDatabase(PWD);
    }
```

MyContentProvider.java

```
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.net.Uri;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import roboguice.content.RoboContentProvider;

public class MyContentProvider extends RoboContentProvider {

    @Inject
    MyOpenHelper openHelper;

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                        String sortOrder) {
        try {
            SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
            qb.setTables(parsePath(uri));
            SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

            // Tell the cursor what uri to watch, so it knows when its source data changes
            c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            return c;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long rowId = db.insert(parsePath(uri), null, initialValues);
        if (rowId > 0) {
            Uri noteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, rowId);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(noteUri, null);
            return noteUri;
        }
        throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int i = db.delete(parsePath(uri), where, whereArgs);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int count = db.update(parsePath(uri), values, where, whereArgs);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return count;
    }

    public String parsePath(Uri uri) {
        String path = uri.getPath();
        return parsePath(path);
    }

    public String parsePath(String path) {
        //TODO implement method correctly using RegExp
        //When update gnerates must return following string /table_name/id
        int index = path.indexOf("/");
        if (index < 0) {
            return path;
        } else {
            index = path.lastIndexOf("/");
            if (index > 0) {
                String str = path.substring(index + 1, path.length());
                try {
                    Integer.valueOf(str);
                    return parsePath(path.substring(0, index));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    return str;
                }
            } else {
                return path.replace("/", "");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Since I have no idea why this error happens still unable to resolve the issue. Can somebody please give suggestions.

FYI:  It is a Salesforce application using Salesforce Android Mobile SDK. and uses 2 ContentProviders one for salesforce SmartStore SyncAdapter. But I think it does not have impact on this issue

Comment: Is there a chance you are deleting the database when logging out? This is the exception you get when trying to access a non - existing DB file.

Comment: I am executing this statement on logout for clearing a table. getContentResolver().delete(MyEntity.CONTENT_URI,"",new String[0]);

When watching the file using (Device Monitor) I can see the file still there.

Comment: I would recommend you check if the DB file exists on the device after logging out. The next thing to check is to make sure you are using the correct password.

Comment: When watching the file using (Device Monitor) I can see the file still there. How could it be wrong password since I am using the constant String for storing the password ?